# How to tweet with Line Break (Twitter Rest API via Fabric)

Tags: ios, swift, api, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm developing a application for iOS(Swift).

I'm afraid my expressions may be rude or hard to read, because I'm not so good at English.
Sorry for any inconvinience I may cause you.

I asked same question on [Twitter Developer Forums](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-tweet-with-line-break-via-fabric-rest-api/59289).

---

I'm trying to make tweet with "Line Break".

For example

```
Hello!
World!
```

---

So I tried to use Rest API via Fabric. But it doesn't work.

My code is...

```
let endPoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
var clientError : NSError?

var tweetText = self.contentTextView.text
tweetText = tweetText.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "\n\r")
let params = ["status" : tweetText]

let request = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("POST", URL: endPoint, parameters: params, error: &clientError)

Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
            if (connectionError == nil) {
                print(“success")
            }else {
                print(“failure: \(connectionError)")
            }
  }
```

In this code, “contentTextView.text" is text which I want to tweet.
I tried to change line break code “\n”,”\r”,”\n\r” and “%0D%0A”, but it didn’t work too.

---

Error message is...

```
failure: Optional(Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=32 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401), NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error : Could not authenticate you. (code 32)})
```

---

If contentTextView.text doesn’t contain “\n” (in other words single line), I can tweet correctly.

For example

```
Hello!World!
```

---

How can I do?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

If I remove the line below, I get same error.

```
tweetText = tweetText.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "\n\r")
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't replace "\n"?

By this, I mean remove the line

```
tweetText = tweetText.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "\n\r")
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. If I remove this line, I get same error too. (Update Question)